# iOS & Xcode 6: Auto Layout Text Scaling on a Button

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, autolayout, xcode6

I have a Today Extension with a button and UIImage. The button and image scale and center themselves correctly except the button's text is not scaled. I am writing this extension in Swift. I have tried these so far:

```
myButton.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
myButton.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

Both return errors.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more code or the specific errors, the only thing I can see is that titleLabel is an optional.  As written, the compiler would show the error `'UILabel? does not have a member named 'adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth'`.  Writing the line as `myButton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true` should fix the error.

Also, UIButton doesn't have a member named 'adjustFontSizeToFitWidth' so the second line would throw the same error as above.

Try fixing that error as indicated above and see if your AutoLayout issue works.